# Find out if there is any rows in SQLCommand query

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have some code like this

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='h'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'") 

conn.Open() 

Dim query As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @sql varchar(1000) Select @investor = 69836 select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(db,''SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor = ''''' + @investor + ''''''')' EXEC(@sql)", conn) 

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader 
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

I need to add in an `If` statement basically saying if the SQLCommand `query` returns no rows then show a specific label

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='h'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'") 

conn.Open() 

Dim query As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @sql varchar(1000) Select @investor = 69836 select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(db,''SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor = ''''' + @investor + ''''''')' EXEC(@sql)", conn) 

Dim rdr as SqlDataReader
rdr = query.ExecuteReader()

if (rdr.HasRows) then
   dgBookings.DataSource = rdr
   dgBookings.DataBind() 
else
    .....
end if
```

Obviously you could do with ensuring the objects are cleaned up/disposed of, so this is just to demonstrate `HasRows` ;)

Comment: This works without the `dgBookings.DataSource = query.Executereader` when i put that bit in it says `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first`

Comment: Sorry, copy n paste error! corrected now - should have replaced that to use rdr

Answer (score 2):

You are being returned a `SqlDataReader` when you call `ExecuteReader()`, and that `SqlDataReader` has a `HasRows` property you can check.

```
Dim oDR As SqlDataReader = query.ExecuteReader()

If oDR.HasRows Then
  lblNoRows.Visible = False
Else
  lblNoRows.Visible = True
End IF
```